# Why DNS services Like google public DNS and Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 has ipv6 versions?

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, dns

I understand the need for ipv6 as we ran out of ipv4 but dns resolvers like google and cloudflare already have ipv4 addresses for resolving dns and i don't see compatibility as a reason either because whatever supports ipv6 supports ipv4 as well so why dns resolvers like google have ipv6 version too ? is there any benefit ?

Comment: "_because whatever supports ipv6 supports ipv4 as well_" That is not actually true. IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate, incompatible protocols, and support of one does not at all imply support of the other. In fact, there have been questions on several SE sites about people that can get IPv6 but not IPv4 from their ISPs. Questions about how to connect to an IPv4-only server from IPv6, and vice versa, because they can only get IPv6, or they want to connect to an IPv6-only server.

Comment: In fact, one question about it popped up today: "[Since my internet provider remove my IPv4, I have to reconfigure my network and server to add IPv6.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65369465/3745413)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plan for IPv6 is to ultimately *replace* IPv4 in entirety. In the long run, it doesn't make sense to run two full stacks in parallel.

Also, some providers serve their clients using IPv4 private addressing ([DS-Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#Dual-Stack_Lite_.28DS-Lite.29) or non-standard [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) addresses), so the only untranslated addresses these clients can use are v6.